# GET request not found

Tags: django, django-urls

In my application, I have various `articles` users can create with a `category` field that I want to serve as a tagging system. On the left hand side of my application, I'd like these categories to be listed so users can filter by interest but I'm currently unable to get it working. The error I'm getting is listed below:

> Using the URLconf defined in bitpoll.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^articles/ ^all/$
> ^articles/ ^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
> ^articles/ ^category/(?P<article_category>\d+)/$
> ^admin/
> ```
>
> The current URL, articles/category/electronics, didn't match any of
>   these.

My code can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/atom-morgan/BitPoll) and the location of the error is in `/article/urls.py`.

Clicking on a specific `article` in `/article/templates/articles.html` works just fine but it doesn't work for my categories and it seems to me like they're setup the exact same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your articles route the regex is looking for digits.  Correct the regex to match any characters that can occur in your article_category field.  For example, the `\w` matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore.

```
^articles/ ^category/(?P<article_category>\w+)/$
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. The downside to following along with tutorials, I guess. Regex is one of those cases where people usually say, "Just write it like this and I'll explain it in more detail later" which causes problems when I try to do stuff on my own like this :)

I was sure it had to be something simple.